# How to open Mac terminal at a specific directory using python + applescript script

Tags: python, macos, terminal, applescript

```
    from applescript import tell 
 
    command = 'cd Downloads/"SSR Drive"'
    yourCommand = "PERF -i "+str(x)+" -u CFG.txt"
    tell.app( 'Terminal', 'do script "' + command + '"')
    tell.app( 'Terminal', 'do script "' + yourCommand + '"')
```

I am using this code to execute commands on Mac Terminal with my python script.

"command" tells the terminal to open the directory

"yourCommand" tells the terminal to execute a biopython module function.

But when I execute, the commands are executed on separate Terminal windows. Resulting in "command" going to the directory, but then "yourCommand" is also executed in a new Terminal. So the directory change I specified with "command" doesn't take effect. Hence, "yourCommand" can't find the file.

I read you can change the default for Terminal to open the current directory instead of the default directory, but that seems like a crude solution.

What I'd like to do is open Terminal on a specified directory and then run the "yourCommand" code in the terminal.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Simply join the commands to be a single one with `&&`.

```
from applescript import tell 
 
command = 'cd Downloads/"SSR Drive"'
yourCommand = "PERF -i "+str(x)+" -u CFG.txt"
tell.app( 'Terminal', 'do script "' + command + ' && ' + yourCommand + '"')
```